# Toggling z-index of overlapping divs with jQuery issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HamishT/4Lhyaxwn/ . Everything works as wanted - when clicked, the div comes to the front. However, when a div to the right of another is clicked then the one to the left of it is clicked, the right hand div stays on top (this may be easier to understand simply by playing around with the jsfiddle - you'll see what I mean). What is causing this and what should I do to prevent it?

Here is my js:

```
var degrees = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 40;

var flag = 0;

$(".rotate").click(function() {
    if (flag == 0) {
        flag = 1;
        $(this).css({
            '-webkit-transform': 'rotate('+degrees+'deg) scale(2)',
            '-moz-transform': 'rotate('+degrees+'deg) scale(2)',
            '-ms-transform': 'rotate('+degrees+'deg) scale(2)',
            '-o-transform': 'rotate('+degrees+'deg) scale(2)',
            'transform': 'rotate('+degrees+'deg) scale(2)',
            'z-index': '100'
        });
        degrees = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 40;
    } else {
        flag = 0;
        $(this).css({
            '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(0deg)',
            '-moz-transform': 'rotate(0deg)',
            '-ms-transform': 'rotate(0deg)',
            '-o-transform': 'rotate(0deg)',
            'transform': 'rotate(0deg)',
            'z-index': '10'
        });
    };
});
```

From what I can work out (I may be wrong) is that the z-index back to 10 isn't working correctly.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is that your z-index on `.rotate` isn't working at all.

If you set `position: relative;` on `.rotate`, all will work as expected.

More information on how z-index works can be found at [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/).

Answer (score 0):

Add `position:relative` to `.rotate` and add .addClass('up').siblings('.rotate.up').css('z-index','99'); to the line applied to the upper elements

see [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/henser/4Lhyaxwn/8/) to see it in action

changes were the following:

JS

```
var degrees = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 40;

var flag = 0;

$(".rotate").click(function() {
    if (flag == 0) {
        flag = 1;
        $(this).css({
            '-webkit-transform': 'rotate('+degrees+'deg) scale(2)',
            '-moz-transform': 'rotate('+degrees+'deg) scale(2)',
            '-ms-transform': 'rotate('+degrees+'deg) scale(2)',
            '-o-transform': 'rotate('+degrees+'deg) scale(2)',
            'transform': 'rotate('+degrees+'deg) scale(2)',
            'z-index': '100'
        }).addClass('up').siblings('.rotate.up').css('z-index','99');
        degrees = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 40;
    } else {
        flag = 0;
        $(this).css({
            '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(0deg)',
            '-moz-transform': 'rotate(0deg)',
            '-ms-transform': 'rotate(0deg)',
            '-o-transform': 'rotate(0deg)',
            'transform': 'rotate(0deg)',
            'z-index': '10'
        });
    };
});
```

CSS

```
.rotate {
    position:relative;
    height:98px;
    width:98px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    background-color:#f00;
    float:left;
    margin:10px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    z-index:10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just do this

```
$(".rotate").click(function() {
   if (flag == 0) {
       flag = 1;
       $(this).css({
        '-webkit-transform': 'rotate('+degrees+'deg) scale(2)',
        '-moz-transform': 'rotate('+degrees+'deg) scale(2)',
        '-ms-transform': 'rotate('+degrees+'deg) scale(2)',
        '-o-transform': 'rotate('+degrees+'deg) scale(2)',
        'transform': 'rotate('+degrees+'deg) scale(2)',
        'position': 'relative',
        'z-index': '100'
    });
    degrees = (Math.random() - 0.5) * 40;
    $(this).siblings(".rotate").css({'z-index':'99'});
} else {
    flag = 0;
    $(this).css({
        '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(0deg)',
        '-moz-transform': 'rotate(0deg)',
        '-ms-transform': 'rotate(0deg)',
        '-o-transform': 'rotate(0deg)',
        'transform': 'rotate(0deg)',
        'position': 'static',
        'z-index': '10'
    });
};
```

});